# ignore some values in insert into select from sql stament

Tags: sql, select, insert

Suppose that I have a Table Symbols(Symbol, Value) and a Table SymbolValues (Symbol, Value) which contains a list of values for the symbol.
How to choose maximum values fromt he SymbolValues table and insert into Symbols table. 
For Example, The SymbolValues Table has following values

```
A 1
A 2
A 3
B 6
B 7
```

Then only A 3 and B 7 should be inserted in the Symbols table.

Is this possible using insert into select statement.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Something like this:

```
insert into symbols(symbol,value)
  (select symbol, max(value) from symbolvalues group by symbol);
```

Comment: I think you should group by symbol

Answer (score 2):

You could modify your select query to be something like:

```
SELECT v.symbol, v.value
FROM SymbolValues v
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM SymbolValues v2 WHERE v2.symbol = v.symbol AND v2.value > v.value)
```

Comment: I think you mean "AND v2.value > v.value"